# How can we save a thread for next task after its execution in java (Implementation of Thread pooling ) 

Tags: java, threadpool

I need to ask about how thread pooling is implemented for having constant number of thread executing each time when there is task submission happened . (In Executor  to avoid each time thread creation and deletion overhead)

```
executor.submit(Runnable)
```

Lets say we create some threads in the start and when task come we assign task to them(Thread) using any Queue impl . But after completing it s task how could a thread return to its pool again when as per the lifecycle of thread says that

"After execution of its run method it goes into TERMINATED state and can't be used again"

I am not understood how thread pool works for having constant number of threads for execution of any task to its queue .

It would be great if anyone could provide me an example of thread reuse after its completion of task .

!!Thanks in advance .!!

Comment: Conceptually it's easy.  You start a fixed number of theads whose run methods wait on a queue.  You send work requests to the queue, the run methods dequeue the requests, and execute the work request.  Then they return to wait on the queue again.  The trick is finding the right type of queue -- there are a half-dozen in the JDK, but only one special one (last I looked) that was suited for this, and it was hidden in a corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "After execution of its run method it goes into TERMINATED state and can't be used again"

It doesn't finish its `run()` Instead it has a loop which runs the run() of the tasks you provide it.

---

Simplifying the thread pool pattern dramatically you have code which looks like this.

```
final BlockingQueue<Runnable> tasks = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();

public void submit(Runnable runs) {
    tasks.add(runs);
}

volatile boolean running = true;

// running in each thread in the pool
class RunsRunnable implement Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while(running) {
           Runnable runs = tasks.take();
           try {
              runs.run();
           } catch(Throwable t) {
              // handles t
           }
        }
    }
 }
```

In this example, you can see that while the run() of each task completes, the run() of the thread itself does not until the pool is shutdown.

Comment: But If we execute run method directly then no thread would be spawn .It would only execute the method . So does it mean execute (in customized impl) can accept  any task which will have the same contract (like Runnable has run()) and we have to call that contract method in pool thread . No use of Runnable or Callable as a task ?

Comment: I have added an example. I think you are assuming that when Runtime.run() returns, something special happens when its just a method call like any other.  A thread stops when there is nothing more for it to do. BTW The UncaughtExceptionHandler can be called after run() exits so a thread doesn't terminate immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Usually what happens when we use thread pool , Its inside Run method it is forced to run iteratively. Until there are tasks available in the Queue.

in the below example pool.removeFromQueue() will run iteratively.

```
public class MyThread<V> extends Thread {
    private MyThreadPool<V> pool;
    private boolean active = true;

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setPool(MyThreadPool<V> p) {
        pool = p;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if there are any unfinished tasks left. if there are , then runs
     * the task and call back with output on resultListner Waits if there are no
     * tasks available to run If shutDown is called on MyThreadPool, all waiting
     * threads will exit and all running threads will exit after finishing the
     * task
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ResultListener<V> result = pool.getResultListener();
        Callable<V> task;
        while (true) {
            task = pool.removeFromQueue();
            if (task != null) {
                try {
                    V output = task.call();
                    result.finish(output);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    result.error(e);
                }
            } else {
                if (!isActive())
                    break;
                else {
                    synchronized (pool.getWaitLock()) {
                        try {
                            pool.getWaitLock().wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void shutdown() {
        active = false;
    }
```

Need to design your thread pool

```
public MyThreadPool(int size, ResultListener<V> myResultListener) {
        tasks = new LinkedList<Callable<V>>();
        threads = new LinkedList<MyThread<V>>();
        shutDown = false;
        resultListener = myResultListener;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            MyThread<V> myThread = new MyThread<V>();
            myThread.setPool(this);
            threads.add(myThread);
            myThread.start();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0730/index.html for more details and an implementation example. The threads in the pool will wait if the queue is empty and will each start consome messages once they are notified that the queue has some elements.

Comment: same question here . Why it is necessary to have task as Runnable or Callable when their only use to call their contract method .
 r = (Runnable) queue.removeFirst();
 r.run();

Is it necessary to have Runnable only . we can porvide any other object which has run method . As its ultimately goal is to be called    using pooling threads not more than that ?

Answer (score 0):

`ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);`

**-** The above statement created a ThreadPool with fixed size of 2.

`executor.execute(new Worker());`

**-** The above statement takes an instance of the class Worker which has implemented `Runnable` Interface.

**-** Now here the `Executors` is an intermediate object, executing the task. Which manages the Thread Objects.

**-** By executing the above statement the `run()` method will be executed, and once the run() method completes, the thread **doesNot** go into dead state but moves back into the pool, waiting to have another work assigned to it, so it can once again move into Runnable state and then to running, all this is handled by Executors .

`executor.shutdown();`

**-** The above statement will shutdown the Executors itself, gracefully handling the shutdown of all the threads managed by it..`shutdown()` on that central object, which in turn could terminate each of the registered executors.

```
////////// Edited Part//////////////////////
```

**-** First of all Runnable has a run() method which canNot return anything, and run() method canNot throw a checked exception, So Callable was introduced in Java 5, which is of Parametric type , and has a method called call(), and it is capable of returning , and throwing Checked exceptions.

**Now see this Example:**

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Worker());

t.run();

t.start();
```

**-** `t.run()` is just a simple call to `run()` method, **this won't span** a `thread of execution`.

**-** `t.start()` whereas prepares for the things important for the `initialization` of the `thread of execution`, and then **calls** the `run()` method of the `Runnable`, and then **assign** the `Task` to the **newly formed** `thread of execution`, and **returns quickly....**

Threads in Java becomes a necessity when using `Swing` and `AWT`. **Mainly the GUI component**.

Comment: @Vivek can you please answer the question i asked in below question . why task as Runnable or Callable . Can i give any obj which has run() method in it.As pooling thread is calling only run() not creating any thread from it . So no Runnable required actually ?

Comment: so in executor case , t.run() is working as we are not creating any t.start()  call when executing the task . So this is same as providing any task which may not be implementation of Runnable but it has run() method . As Executor 's PoolWorker only executing of run method (like t.run()) no use of thread qualities in task ?

Comment: @Virendra There are **2 ways to use thread**, `either implements Runnable Inteface or extends Thread Class`. **Thread Class implements Runnable**, so it has to implement the run() method of Runnable Interface. Now **Executors manages Thread Object, so we don't need to handle the life-cycle of the Thread**. Now when we say t.run() only run() method will execute, **But on the same thread**..... calling start() will lead to the creation of `thread of execution`, and **allocating the time taking task to run on a separate thread.**

Answer (score 0):

I am totally agree with Peter but want add steps related to ExecutorService execution flow, for clear understanding.

- If you create pool (*fixed size pool*) of threads it does not means that threads were created.
- If you submit and/or execute new Task (`Runnuble` or `Callable`) new thread will be created JUTS if count of created threads `<` size of pool
- Created threads not returning to pool, threads can wait for new value in blocking queue, this point we can call RETURNING TO POOL
- All threads from pool execs like Peter described above.